# Adjusting fragments height according the pixel position scroll on a list inside one of the fragments (Android)

Tags: android, scroll, height, fragment

Ok, I have a LinerLayout vertical in which there are three fragments, lets say: HeaderFragment, SubHeaderFragment and ListViewFragment (fragment with listview in it). These are put in the layout in this order, width set to match_parent. The header and subheader fragments have a defined height, lets say 100dp each. The list fragment's height is set to wrap_content.

Now, what I want to do is that when the list fragment is scrolled down, the SubHeader fragment should loose its height (according to the amount scrolled) until it disappears and the user checks the list. If the user scrolls back up to the beggining of the list the SubHeader fragment should get its height back, again according to the scrolling.
This can be seen in several Apps, for better use of the screen size.

I have researched quite a bit, but I found no simple solution to this. One would be to keep track of the scrolling position of the list and reset the heights dynamicly while this is done. Which is trouble because as far as I know the scroll position for the list must be calculated and I am dealing with fragments that have no layout params.
Another idea I had was to put the SubHeader and the List Fragments in a scrollview within the linear layout, but that destroys my list within its fragment and people say it shouldnt be done due to bad performance.

Is there a decent simple solution for this? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: why don't you use scroll view inside the linear layout..

Comment: I tried that, but then my list only shows the first item.
Also, i read that we shouldnt have a listview inside a scrollview (??)